# SQL Server: is it possibile to use UPDLOCK with non-clustered index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, transactions, locking

In my database need to lock all agenda records of a given day, so I perform:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION T1
select *
from DBName.dbo.Agenda WITH (UPDLOCK)
where day='2017-04-20'
/* COMMIT TRANSACTION T1 */
```

then, in the meanwhile I've tried with

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION T2
select *
from DBName.dbo.Agenda WITH (UPDLOCK)
where day='2017-04-18'
COMMIT TRANSACTION T2
```

Anyway transaction T2 is blocked until T1 has finished, even if the records filtered by the where clause are different. 
In a post here on SO, I've read that I sould add an index to the day of the agenda in order that only the days matching the where clause are locked. This does not seem to work, maybe because the index is supposed to be clustered by in my Agenda table I already have a clustered index (the prima key, which is a counter integer). So, is there any other option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three options to get the [Key-Range Locking](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191272(v=sql.105).aspx) behavior you want for `select *`:

1. Clustered index on `day`
2. Unique index on `day`
3. Covering nonclustered index on `day`

An example for the covering nonclustered index:

```
create table dbo.agenda (
    id int not null identity (1, 1) primary key clustered
  , [day] date
  , comment varchar(64) not null default newid()
);
insert into dbo.agenda ([day]) values 
('20170417') ,('20170418') ,('20170419') ,('20170420') ,('20170421'),('20170422'); 

create nonclustered index ix_agenda_day on dbo.agenda ([day]) include (id, comment);
```

Then running the two transactions in separate sessions, and using [**`sp_WhoIsActive`** by Adam Machanic](http://whoisactive.com).

[image]

---

If you were only selecting `[day]` or `id, [day]` (since the clustering key is included in the nonclustered index), then your noncovering nonclustered index would provide the behavior you want and lock the key range using that index.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you kind reply SqlZim. It sounds really interesting and I will try it tomorrow in the morning as soon as I arrive at the office. Even if I have read the article you linked, I'm afraid I have not understood much about Key-Range Locking and "covering nonclustered index". Why a field "comment" is needed? I will try to read some more documentation but I'm not an advanced expert of DBMS unfortunately...

Comment: In reality, all this mess comes out because, according to some requirements, only a limited number of agendas can be created per day, so only one user at a time (before performing an INSERT INTO query) can know the number of existing agendas of that day. That's why I need to lock the records while the decision is being taken...and the UPDLOCK seems to be the only one whichs works for me. I've also tried SERIALIZABLE TRANSACTION LEVEL which, according documentation, should lock the records read with a SELECT QUERY but this doesn't happen.

Comment: @LoryLory The `comment` field was necessary for my example to demonstrate the difference between `select *` and `select [date]`. For `select *`, you would need to `include()` all the other columns in the index. If you `select [date]` then you don't need to include all of the other columns.

Comment: in effect, I'm an idiot because there's no real need to select all the columns. It's enough to select the ID and the date (included in the index as you said) and nothing more. Can't really wait to try it tomorrow. Thank you mate!

Comment: @LoryLory I didn't know if there was a reason to select all columns or not, but glad you've got it sorted out now.